# ASP.Net MVC connections trying to remote SQL Server, unexpectedly creating a table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am using the following connection string to connect to a SQL Server database

```
Data Source=ip,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=dev_user;Password=testPassword
```

But instead of connecting, I am getting the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'mydb'.
> Installing Hangfire SQL objects...
> Database schema [HangFire] already exists'

Why is it creating a database instead of connecting to SQL Server?

I have tried setting with Integrated Security to either true or SSPI, but I'm getting this error:

> The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI contex" error instead

What am I missing?

Comment: The permission denied message seems a bit sus. Verify dev_user has permission to modify the schema (easiest way on a dev instance is to assign dev_user the db_owner role under mydb >> Security >> Users or grant the dev_user sysadmin privileges on the server Security >> Logins).

Comment: You seemed to miss that Hangfire creates tables in the nominated database for job storage. Ref: [Hangfire Overview # Job Storage](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/#job-storage) and [Using SQL Server](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html).

Comment: @AlanSamet was right, the user seems to miss role or priviledges, that solves the issue, thanks!